# localleader is not obeyed

Tags: vimrc, snippets, leader

for my `fortran` code, I have defined:

```
au FileType fortran let maplocalleader = "`"   # i have tried \` as well.
```

For `fortran` filetype in vim, `:echo maplocalleader` is showing **`** 
as expected.

But, then, with my keyboard mapping as(inside a `ftplugin`):

```
inoremap <localleader>wr      pr<c-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>
```

or anything like this, defined `localleader` is not honoured. Rather the expansion is working with `\`.

I am unable to guess what the problem is.

Any help please?

I am in vim8

Answer (score 4):

When you register it this way, your new autocommand will be triggered after all other autocommands registered on the same event, in particular after the one that sources your ftplugin -- I suppose you define the mapping in an ftplugin (*).

You could change that, probably by changing the order between this line and the `:filetype xxxx` in your .vimrc, but this is not the right solution.

Unlike what its name implies, *localleader* is global. Somehow, I guess it's indeed meant to be used from filetype plugins, and buffer local-mappings, but you shall define it in your `.vimrc`, once and for all, and for all filetypes.

(*) if the mapping is defined in your `.vimrc`, it has even less chances to work as you were expecting as the corresponding line would be sourced before any event is happening. IOW, the mapping would be defined before the filetype(=fortran)  event happens.

Comment: This is what :h <localleader> says:
 <LocalLeader> is to be used for mappings which are
local to a buffer.  Example: >
      :map <buffer> <LocalLeader>A  oanother line<Esc>

Comment: @BaRud, yet, it's a global (`g:`) variable, not a buffer-local one (`b:`), which implies it cannot be set in a reaction of a filetype-related event without asking for troubles -- I was making that mistake until recently ^^'

Comment: @BaRud when you do the `map` command, it uses whatever the current value of localleader or leader is, so you must change it ahead of time to take effect (ie, changing my leader after creating some maps with it does *not* change those maps)

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble: you mean my maps in ftplugin is loded first, precede by au command in vimrc?

Comment: @BaRud no—steps: 1. Autocommand defined. 2. Edit fortan file. 3. Ftplugins for fortran load. 4. Autocommands for fortran fire. Do you see why the autocommand can’t affect the mappings?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Thanks. Its solved by definig a variable: `let g:VimF90Leader = "\`"`

Comment: @BaRud, Do you really want to use different leaders for different filetypes? At some point in time, I though that's want I wanted. Then I've been pestering about ft-specialized mappings that did not trigger -- just because my leader wasn't the same. `maplocalleader` is a global variable (meant to be set in the .vimrc), and now I understand why it makes sense.